# What would be the best way to display "Content submitted" confirmation message after an user posts a question / answer / comment?

Tags: feedback, confirmation, question-answer

Usually it is displayed similarly to this:

**[Your content has been submitted - System message]**

[Content - Copy of the content that will be visible]

[Edit | Remove]

Comment: Seems a pretty sensible way and commonly used. Although there's not that much detail to go on.

Answer (score 1):

What you have mentioned is a pretty sensible way of going about it. Also, it depends on how your other system / site messages are shown to the user. You need to be consistent.

Why do you want to show the copy of content that is visible? Intuitiveness and confirmation is okay, but beyond that what is the reason? Instead I would recommend the new content to be visible on screen behind the message, or some visual cue that user can go and see that content somewhere.

A confirmation message should not be so big that is disconnects your user from what that page otherwise displays. It should just notify the user of success and failure, and ways to visit the successful page, or correct the error state.

Also, a message becomes redundant if your system redirects the user to whatever that he has submitted.

Further I can comment about specificities, if you give more details about your requirements.

Hope I have helped.